# Exact $\Delta$ - System Lemma

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

The well-known $\Delta$-system lemma states:

> Each uncountable family of finite sets has an uncountable sub-family with a root. Precisely:
>
> $$\forall F~~~(|F|>\aleph_0~\wedge~\forall X\in F~~~|X|<\aleph_0)\longrightarrow$$
> $$(\exists \Delta~\exists F'\subseteq F~~~|F'|>\aleph_0~\wedge~\forall X,Y\in F'~(X\neq Y\rightarrow X\cap Y=\Delta))$$

For which uncountable families of finite sets like $F$ is the following version of $\Delta$-system lemma true?

$$\forall F~~~(|F|>\aleph_0~\wedge~\forall X\in F~~~|X|<\aleph_0)\longrightarrow$$
$$(\exists \Delta~\exists F'\subseteq F~~~|F'|=|F|~\wedge~\forall X,Y\in F'~(X\neq Y\rightarrow X\cap Y=\Delta))$$

I am looking for an "intuitive" necessary and sufficient condition on $F$.

Comment: If $|F|$ is a regular cardinal, then this is true. If $|F|$ is singular, it can be false.

Comment: @William How to build a model of ZFC in which exact $\Delta$-system lemma fails?

Comment: No this is not a consistency result. It is always false.

Comment: @William Ah! I got the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\kappa$ be a singular cardinal with $\text{cf}(\kappa) = \lambda < \kappa$.

Write $\kappa - \lambda = \bigsqcup_{\alpha < \lambda} U_\alpha$ where $|U_\alpha|<\kappa$.

Let $F = \{ \ \{\alpha, \beta\} : \alpha < \lambda \wedge \beta \in U_\alpha\}$.

Note $|F| = \kappa$. Since the $U_\alpha$ are disjoint partition of $\kappa - \lambda$, the root of any $\Delta$-system must be a singleton $\{\alpha\}$ for some $\alpha < \lambda$. However, if $x \cap y = \{\alpha\}$ for $x,y \in F$, then $x,y \in U_\alpha$. $|U_\alpha| < \kappa$. Hence there is no $\Delta$-system of size $\kappa$.